# Why java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in same package?

Tags: java, android, class, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-dependencies

Class  A  references a Class B. They are in the same package. So A does not import B. And no compile error appears. But when I get A class Object and calling ClassA.getDeclaredMethods, exception happens:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: xxx.xxx.B ?

But when I  import Class B's parent interface in A and  change A's method return type from B to B's parent interface  clearly at the same time.  It's OK.

I try two android device and the error both happens.

Why?

PS: I got the reason for this from log

```
04-21 21:31:25.005 W/dalvikvm(21707): Class resolved by unexpected DEX: Lxxx/xxxx/xxxx/methods/FieldsConfig;(0x42a18bd8):0x76e66000 ref [Lxxx/xxxx/xxxx/ITelephonyManagerInterface$IFieldsConfig;] Lxxx/xxxx/xxxx/ITelephonyManagerInterface$IFieldsConfig;(0x42a18bd8):0x76d17000
04-21 21:31:25.005 W/dalvikvm(21707): (Lxxx/xxxx/xxxx/methods/FieldsConfig; had used a different Lxxx/xxxx/xxxx/ITelephonyManagerInterface$IFieldsConfig; during pre-verification)
04-21 21:31:25.005 W/dalvikvm(21707): Link of class 'Lxxx/xxxx/xxxx/methods/FieldsConfig;' failed
```

I load one class from two dex.

```
    compile project(":base")

    androidTestCompile project(':AAAA')  // only androidTest
    androidTestCompile project(':BBBB')
    androidTestCompile project(':CCCC') {
        exclude project(":base")  //how I exclude one project??
    }//only androidTest
```

Now another question comes.
How can I exclude the project(":base")  from androidTestCompile project(':CCCC') ?

Comment: You tagged this question as 'reflection'. Are you actually using reflection? What does your code look like? Do you use proguard to remove unused classes?

Comment: Show us some code.

Comment: @dsh OP claims that he get problem with `getDeclaredMethods` which kind of is one of reflection mechanism. But I agree about rest of your questions. We need [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) / [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and precise info about project structure.

Comment: @OP are you able to reproduce this problem in non-android environment?